# printf; exception in thread, illegal format conversion

Tags: java, printf

The program compiles fine, but I get the following runtime error:

Food          Source Digestion Available
*******        Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Nutrition.main(Nutrition.java:22)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nutrition
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String HEADING_STR = "%-10s%10s%10s%10s\n";
    final String DATA_STR = "%-15s%,10.1f%,10.1f.0%,10.1f\n";
    double protein1 = 150; // protein in chicken
    double digested1 = 50; // chicken digested
    double protein2 = 120; // protein in beef
    double digested2 = 30; // beef digested
    double availableProtein1, availableProtein2; // protein after digestion

    System.out.printf (HEADING_STR, "Food", "Source", "Digestion", "Available");
    System.out.printf (DATA_STR, "*******", "*******", "*******", "*******");

    availableProtein1 = protein1 - digested1;
    System.out.printf(DATA_STR, "Chicken", protein1, digested1, availableProtein1);
} // end main
} // end Nutrition
```

Comment: Please read the exception. Looks like you are using `f` and giving it a string, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     final String DATA_STR = "%-15s%,10.1f%,10.1f.0%,10.1f\n"; 
   ... other code
     System.out.printf (DATA_STR, "*******", "*******", "*******", "*******");
```

`DATA_STR` requires one `String` and a bunch of `float` arguments while you are passing strings here